# border-bottom attribute on span affects all borders of the respective element in outlook365

Tags: outlook, html-email

My company is using Adobe dreamweaver to generate HTML emails, and oftentimes it doesnt work or provide the features desired. So I have to step in and make the HTML-Emails work at least in our Office365 environment...

However, to the point: Above some text, a green line/border shall be displayed. So I went into the sourcecode, looked up the containing element and added a span tag around the word supposed to have a green top-border. Then I added

```
style="border-top: 5px solid green"
```

And when I insert the HTML Code into an email, I get the display of a word being completely surrounded by green borders, not just a green top border.

The span tag resides within b tags, and the b tages are inside a td and so on. Nothing special in my opinion.

i already tried working around this by using other elements that span, but it didnt work. Oftentimes it seems as if Outlook doesnt even recognize the tags.

```
display: inline
```

also didnt have any effect on div element, which I had high hopes for since at least there, the border-top activated only the top border, not all borders around it. But unfortunately, its not inline...^^

Any experienced HTML-Email designers out there who would have some advice or two?

EDIT:
Part of the markup

```
                        <td height="100" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" class="inner" style="border-left-color: #000000:; border-left: thin; padding-top:15px; padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:30px; font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:100%; color:#000000; font-weight:normal;">
                            <table width="547" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <tr>
                            <td width="539" height="40" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="inner" style="padding-top:15px; padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:30px; font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:100%; color:#000000; font-weight:normal;"> <b><span style="border-top: 5px solid green;">TEST</span> - blablabla</b>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
```

Comment: Could you post a piece of your markup which shows where the issue is?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev Added some markup :)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a Span tag to do this. You need a block element to add a border to (e.g. div / td).
I would suggest utilizing tables and table cells. It'll be your best way to add the border in a way that is supported everywhere and keep everything looking nice, no matter the email client quirks.

See my edits below:

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
     <td height="100" bgcolor="#EFEFEF" class="inner" style="border-left-color: #000000:; border-left: thin; padding-top:15px; padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:30px; font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:100%; color:#000000; font-weight:normal;">
            <table width="547" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#ffffff" class="inner" style="padding-top:15px; padding-right:15px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-left:30px;">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                 <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:auto;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:100%; color:#000000; font-weight:normal; border-top: 5px solid green; padding-top:3px;">
                                                <b>TEST</b>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    
                                 <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:auto;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="font-family:'Segoe UI', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:100%; color:#000000; font-weight:normal; border-top: 5px solid #ffffff; padding-top:3px;">
                                                <b>- blablabla</b>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```